# Is it possible to design molecules of desired qualities?

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I was thinking if it would be possible to take into account every property of every atom known to man so that they can compute any type of compound they want. Is it possible to accomplish something like that with the present computation technologies or are the variables that are accounted in making of any kind of molecule and determining its properties too high?

Comment: I don't think it is even possible to *enumerate* all the possible combinations of every element known so doing properties as well would be a serious stretch.

Comment: But there must be a way to generate some heuristic measure..afterall there already are documents that tell us properties of atoms that make a compound under different conditions and combinations

Comment: _sigh_ You should have some knowledge to properly formulate questions. I _guess_ you're interested in computational design of materials, proteins etc. That's so broad topic that it would be hard to summerise.

Comment: Well...I did ask what came to my mind. I was curious. Needed an idea on where to start looking.

Comment: OK, but for future, questions about specific well described things are much more welcome here than vague ideas, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Your title and the question itself arise *two* different issues, and I'll try to address both.

1. Yes it is possible to design molecules of desired qualities, only it's not all that simple. It requires a great deal of calculations, practice, empirical laws, heuristics, experimentation, guesswork, and magic. Eventually this body of knowledge grew so wide that people started to count it a science in its own right. It became known as ***chemistry***.
2. Yes we can take into account every property of every atom and compute the properties of any compound they constitute. The problem, though, quickly becomes prohibitively expensive in terms of computation time. The reverse problem (to come up with a molecule of desired properties via *calculations alone*) is even more costly.

So it goes.